# Slide up animation when IsVisible is changed in xaml xamarin and C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a class for animation behavior like:

```
public class BaseAnimationBehavior : Behavior<View>
{
    protected View associatedObject;
    protected Easing _easingFunction;

    private readonly BindableProperty EasingFunctionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EasingFunction), typeof(string), typeof(BaseAnimationBehavior), defaultValue: "Linear", propertyChanged: (b, o, n) => OnEasingFunctionChanged(b, (string)o, (string)n));
    private readonly BindableProperty ScaleProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Scale), typeof(double), typeof(BaseAnimationBehavior), defaultValue: 1.25);

    public string EasingFunction
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue(EasingFunctionProperty); }
      set { SetValue(EasingFunctionProperty, value); }
    }

    public double Scale
    {
      get { return (double)GetValue(ScaleProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ScaleProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(View bindable)
    {
      associatedObject = bindable;
      associatedObject.SizeChanged += AnimateItem;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(View bindable)
    {
      associatedObject.SizeChanged -= AnimateItem;
    }

    private static Easing GetEasing(string easingName)
    {
      switch (easingName)
      {
        case "BounceIn": return Easing.BounceIn;
        case "BounceOut": return Easing.BounceOut;
        case "CubicInOut": return Easing.CubicInOut;
        case "CubicOut": return Easing.CubicOut;
        case "Linear": return Easing.Linear;
        case "SinIn": return Easing.SinIn;
        case "SinInOut": return Easing.SinInOut;
        case "SinOut": return Easing.SinOut;
        case "SpringIn": return Easing.SpringIn;
        case "SpringOut": return Easing.SpringOut;
        default: throw new ArgumentException(easingName + " is not valid");
      }
    }

    private static void OnEasingFunctionChanged(BindableObject bindable, string oldvalue, string newvalue)
    {
      var obj = bindable as BaseAnimationBehavior;
      if (obj == null)
      {
        return;
      }

      obj.EasingFunction = newvalue;
      obj._easingFunction = GetEasing(newvalue);
    }

    private void AnimateItem(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
      await associatedObject.TranslateTo(associatedObject.TranslationX, associatedObject.TranslationY - 10, 10, _easingFunction);
      await associatedObject.TranslateTo(associatedObject.TranslationX, associatedObject.TranslationY + 10, 900, _easingFunction);
    }
}
```

in XAML page, I apply animation like:

```
<StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding AProp}">
  <Entry Text="{Binding AField}" IsEnabled="True">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <Entry.Behaviors:BaseAnimationBehavior EasingFunction="SinInOut" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
  </Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

When `AProp` becomes true then animation occur because of `SizeChanged` event.

When `AProp` becomes false then animation won't run or won't be visible because entire StackLayout is hidden.

I use MVVM and I have a view model and it is binded to view like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public bool AProp { get { return _prop; } set { _prop = value; RaisePropertyChanged ....; } }
   public string AField { get { return _field; } set { _field = value; RaisePropertyChanged ....; } }

   public void DoSomething() {
     if(condition) { AProp = true; } else { AProp = false; }
   }
}
```

How to achieve the situation when hide element, to animate first and then hide it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding using the View Model you would need to send some kind of signal to the view that the property has changed.

If you have to hide the control from the View Model for some reason I would suggest

- overriding the RaisePropertyChanged in your view model
- rise an event on the property name is AProb
- subscribe to that event in the view
- finally start your animation manually by giving the Entry a name